# can't close a current window and open new window

Tags: php, html, mysql, header, window.closed

Problem in closing a window.

i am using 4 files.

```
link.html
userdetails.php
ultrapro.php
final.php
```

upto ultrapro.php its working fine like opening and closing

but ultrapro.php file is not closing  and not opening final.html file

**In userdetails.php file** Working

```
$query = array(
    'username' => $_POST['username'], 
    'name' => $_POST['name'],
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'phone' => $_POST['phone']
    );

$query = http_build_query($query);
header("Location: ultrapro1.php?$query");

print "<script>window.close('userdetails.php')</script>";
```

**In ultrapro.php file**  not working

```
header("Location: final.html");

print "<script>window.close('ultrapro.php')</script>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header("Location: final.html");

print "<script>window.close('ultrapro.php')</script>";
```

You're getting redirected earlier then printing the script.

Try:

```
print "<script>window.close('ultrapro.php'); window.location = \"final.html\";</script>";
```